# Properly using .Net entities in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entities

I am following this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467

I have my UserModel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class UserContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However when I run:

```
            using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

I get the error Entity is not mapped...

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I tried using the other method of adding an entity data model but it wouldn't use my primary connection. Please what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Now nothing is going into the database, but I am getting no error, this is what I am doing:

```
    User user = new UserModel();
    user.FirstName = "Please";
    user.LastName = "Work";
    user.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    user.AspNetUserId = new Guid();

    using (var userContext = new UserContext())
    {
        userContext.Users.Add(user);
        userContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have only `User` type `DbSet` in your context and you are trying to save a `UserModel` type object. Change the DbSet declaration to `DbSet<UserModel>`.

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi I did that now I am not getting an error, however nothing is going into the database...

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your context the `State` of the new object.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the default State when you execute `.Add()` is `EntityState.Unchanged` so the context doesn't save anything because as far as its concerned there is nothing to save.

```
using (var userContext = new UserContext()) 
    { 
        userContext.Users.Add(user);
        userContext.entry(user).State = EntityState.Added; 
        userContext.SaveChanges(); 
    }
```

Here is an example from an application I am working on as we speak that compiles/runs/saves to DB

```
       dr405.Transmitted = true;
        dr405.ModDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.dr405s.Add(dr405);
        db.Entry(dr405).State = EntityState.Modified; 
        service.Save(db);
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than that?  What didn't work? Did you get a runtime error?

Comment: The name of your model will be the name of your table can you confirm you have a table named UserModel?  I'm not seeing where the `Users` Type is being created.